# Why do melodies sound empty/bad without context?

Tags: music

Its so strange, if you sing or think of a melody of a famous song you suddenly have the chords in mind, the vocals or the timbre/sound of the instrument that plays the melody. And this makes me think of, woaw what a good melody.

If I make up a melody it always sound so bad until i start to add a harmony or a crazy sound or some vocals and voila it evokes emotions.

But why do i need that context? I ask this because i kinda find it hard to recognise if a melody that i made up is good or not...

Peace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you have a good melody it will stand on its own outside of the context of the chord changes. For example, sing any great melody out of context. Moon River, Somewhere Over the Rainbow, Yesterday, The Sound of Music, God Only Knows.. I think the melody in these example are so strong that they do well to imply the structure without needed a chord bed for context. Now I am the Walrus? Lucy in the Sky With Diamonds? You Are So Beautiful? Not strong melodies at all but sound great in the context of the chord changes. You can always get a second opinion by playing your melodies to folks out of context to see if they "hold up".

Comment: Yeah but I think that even yesterday would sound empty when we would not know the chords and sad voice behind. When i whistle yesterday in my mind I really "feel" the chords, if I had the idea of the melody i can not have this feeling. Its like "yesterday ... feeling changes ... all my trouble seems so far away ... feeling changes twice ... ba boa boa boa..."